# How to Rename a Database without losing data?

Tags: sql-server-2008

HEllo All,
        I am in a problem in my sql database.I have a DB in sql 2005.I just want to rename that DB and want it in sql 2008 without losing its data.For examble,i have a mdf and a ldf file of a DB named "Hello" in sql 2005 with a 1000 data,i want to save this DB in sql 2008 in another name "HAi".Anybody please help me.......

Answer (score 2):

Just go into SQL Server Management Studio, select the database, and press F2.

Comment: You likely don't have permissions to do this.  You should also post your error messages and proper details about exactly what you are trying to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar errors too, when something like this used to pop up I just simply closed the services of the SQL server and restart it. Then I could do the rename and other stuff for a little while before the error showing up again.